# Indy9 does not correctly send HTML when attachments are added

Tags: delphi, html-email, delphi-7, email-attachments

We have a windows service that's written in Delphi 7 that sends out emails containing HTML. This was working perfectly before I added attachments. After adding attachments, the HTML no longer shows as HTML but now shows as plain Text.

After some researching, I found that I have to set the mail content type to `multipart/mixed` however this does not seem change anything. I also found several articles showing that I have to use `MessageParts` when adding multiple content types like the following:

For the attachments I have the following code that works fine.

```pascal
for I := 0 to slAttachments.Count -1 do
begin
  with TIdAttachment.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, slAttachments[I]) do
  begin
    ContentType := 'application/pdf';
  end;
end;
```

Using TIdText as shown below leaves the body of the email empty after sending. Debugging shows that `sMsg` contains the correct HTML but it does not get sent with the email.

```pascal
MailText := TIdText.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, nil);
MailText.ContentType := 'text/html';
MailText.Body.Text := sMsg;
```

If I directly set the `MailMessage` body, the html shows up as plain text.

```pascal
MailMessage.Body.Text := sMsg;
```

Full Code:

```pascal
//setup mail message
MailMessage.From.Address              := msFromAddress;
MailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := sToAddress;
MailMessage.Subject                   := sSubject;
MailMessage.ContentType               := 'multipart/mixed';

// Add Attachments
for I := 0 to slAttachments.Count -1 do
begin
  with TIdAttachment.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, slAttachments[I]) do
  begin
    ContentType := 'application/pdf';
  end;
end;

// Add HTML
MailText := TIdText.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, nil);
MailText.ContentType := 'text/html';
MailText.Body.Text := sMsg;
```

How can I send attachments and have the HTML shown at the same time? The same code works correctly in Delphi 10. I'm not able to upgrade this project to Delphi 10 due to some dependencies. Indy also cannot be upgraded due to breaking changes.

Comment: Delphi 7 uses Indy ver. 9 by default, which is **very** old. You can try excluding Indy 9 from standard Delphi 7 installation and install latest Indy 10 to Delphi 7. Expect some breaking changes.

Comment: Have you read [HTML Messages](https://www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages/) on Indy's site? Using `TIdMessage.MessageParts` and `'multipart/mixed'` is correct, and off-hand the code looks OK, however why are you adding the PDFs in front of the HTML rather than behind it? In theory, that *should* work, but in *practice* I would put the HTML in front instead.

Comment: I have read somewhat part of that yes but not properly like I should have. Thats where I got the code for the attachments etc. I'm not to clued up with how an email containing attachments and HTML should be structured. I will attempt to swap it and see what happens. I'll also read the whole article.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I seemed to have figured it out. I'm unsure why it works. So as you suggested I put the HTML first and then the attachments. This didn't change anything. Still got a empty email with only attachments.

I then added a plain text TIdText with the body of "Test Message" and afterwords another TIdText but this time the HTML. Looking at the email its like the first TIdText isn't being added or sent. Only the second one. I suspect this was a Indy9 bug that was fixed in Indy10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Indy9 where the first TIdText gets ignored when attachments are added. Adding a plain TIdText seems to have fixed this issue.

1. Add a plain text TIdText.
2. Add the HTML TIdText you with the html body you require.
3. Add the attachments.

Tested and working code below. The first TIdText that contains plain text seems to be ignored however when removing it the html gets ignored.

```pascal
// Set content type for the mail message
MailMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';

// Plain text body
With TIdText.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, nil) do
begin
  ContentType := 'text/plain';
  Body.Text := 'This gets ignored for some reason'; // Doesn't have to be empty
end;

// HTML (HTML body to send)
With TIdText.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, nil) do
begin
  ContentType := 'text/html';
  Body.Text := '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
end;

// Attachments
for I := 0 to slAttachments.Count -1 do
begin
  with TIdAttachment.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, slAttachments[I]) do
  begin
    ContentType := 'application/pdf';
  end;
end;

// Send the mail
smtp.Send(MailMessage);
```